# Exercise on maximum modulus principle.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that $\Gamma$ is the boundary of the unbounded region $\Omega$, in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$, continuous in $\Omega \cup \Gamma$, and there exist constants $ B<\infty$ and $M<\infty$ such that $|f|\leq B$ in $\Omega$ and $|f|\leq M$ in $\Gamma$. Prove that $|f|\leq M$ in $\Omega$.

The hint is to consider first the case when $\Omega$ is dense in the Riemann sphere. For the other case i solved the exercise. My problem is that i don't know if by $\Gamma$ the exercise means a curve or an abstract set which is the boundary of $\Omega$.

Comment: Usually $\Gamma$ is used for a curve, but it could mean a general set too. For the validity of the statement, no assumptions about the structure of $\Gamma$ are needed. But I don't know what are the tools you have for this problem, and whether they apply for general domains.

Comment: The tools i have is all the compatible and standard complex function theory.Not something special concearning Julia or Fatou sets.